# Submit abstract to conference with no results yet

Tags: conference, abstract

I am planning to go to a geoscience conference next year and therefore I would like to submit 1-2 abstracts.

Abstracts' submission has a deadline (of course) and I am not sure if I will have good results by then.

Is it acceptable to submit an abstract to a conference without having results yet?

Surely, the abstract will be very general and broad without 'making up' anything about my research's results.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends very much on the conference in question. There are several conferences I submit to where it is fairly routine to outline broad strokes results, with the expectation that they will change in between the submission and the conference. There are others that expressly do not allow this, and want final-form, precise results and prohibit things like "...will be discussed."

So check the conference, and ask your advisor about the norms in your field.

Comment: @aaaaa: We can't provide info on specific conferences. You have to consult the specific guidelines of the conference for that.